Forever running Service for API 34+
I have been researching without results for some time now. A foreground service whose service is forever running needs to be created.
Idea can be found on this gist: https://gist.github.com/varunon9/f2beec0a743c96708eb0ef971a9ff9cd
Issues is that when starting a foreground service from a Worker or from onDestroy() lifecycle callback of the ForegroundService itself the following error would appear:
android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: startForegroundService() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.proxy.service.MyForegroundService

Does someone have an idea on how to implement this properly?

A forever service has never been completely possible in android and now there are even more restrictions where you cannot start a service while your app is in the background. Please see the documentation https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services

I read the documentation before posting this question, am looking to see if someone has found a way to do this

its not possible like I said, the OS can always kill your service if it needs to without notification

No no, assume service is with a notification. Performing a longer running task after that @tyczj

This isn't necessary authoritative.
This is a feature, not a bug.  Services must be capable of being terminated due to the Cybersecurity requirements of a Trusted Computing Base.  Otherwise, it looks very similar to malware or antivirus software.

Thank you Robert, I know that. Thing is sometimes there is a task that needs to be finished at some point later in time. Like finishing some transaction and similar even if the user/OS kills the app. How can that be managed? Foreground service is with the notification but still doesn't run
